# yaml.dump throws an error on numpy.array type attribute of an object in Python

Tags: python, arrays, python-3.x, numpy, yaml

I'd like my object to compactly print itself out (no loading is needed), so that numpy.array is printed as a regular tuple (in this example). Instead, I see an error message `TypeError: data type not understood`.

Any idea what causes an error message and (once resolved) how to

```
class A:
    def __init__(self):
        from numpy import array
        self.a_array = array([1,2,3])

    def __repr__(self):
        from yaml import dump
        return dump(self, default_flow_style=False)

A()
```

Desired output is something like:

```
object:A
a_array: 
- 1, 2, 3
```

Any ideas?

UPDATE: This may work (if implementable): Is there a way to have a yaml representer that replaces any `array` variable `x` to its `x.tolist()` representation?

Comment: How is it supposed to display if the array is 2d (or larger).  Are you interested in small, almost trivial arrays that fit on a human-readable line, or big ones (1000s of elements)?

Comment: I may have larger arrays, but for now, I'd like to understand how to deal with 1D. I can infer the approach to 2D and larger size data :) Thx for clarifying question.

Comment: `x.tolist()` is the easiest way to change the array into something `yaml` knows how to handle.

Comment: Thx! See update. If there is a way to call `tolist()` on `array` variables during `yaml.dump`, it should work cleanly (affecting only `array` types and not any other).

Comment: Have you looked at the `yaml` registration bussiness?  You can write a function that handles a particular class of object, and register that with the `yaml` module.  You could do that with your whole class, and with things like arrays that aren't handled to your satisfaction.  I seen that in the `pyyaml` docs, but never implemented it myself.  http://stackoverflow.com/a/27196166/901925

Comment: Indeed, I thought this may be a feasible solution, but have limited experience with registration of `yaml` representatives (and, could not find sufficient documentation, in particular, about registering `array` structures).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Are you interested in generating valid `yaml`, or just using `yaml` as a way to display your object?  Phrases like 'no load is needed' suggest the latter.

But why focus on `yaml`?  Does it natively handle lists or sequences in the way you want?

If I use `tolist` to turn an array into a list that `yaml` can dump, I get:

```
In [130]: a = np.arange(3)
In [131]: print(yaml.dump({'a':a.tolist()},default_flow_style=False))
a:
- 0
- 1
- 2

In [132]: print(yaml.dump({'a':a.tolist()},default_flow_style=True))
{a: [0, 1, 2]}
```

I could drop the dictionary part.  But either way the list part does not display as:

```
- 1, 2, 3
```

I don't see how `yaml.dump` is any improvement over the default array displays:

```
In [133]: print(a)
[0 1 2]
In [134]: print(repr(a))
array([0, 1, 2])
```

For 2d arrays (and arrays that can be turned into 2d), `np.savetxt` gives a compact display, with `fmt` options to control the details:

```
In [139]: np.savetxt('test',a[None,:], fmt='%d')
In [140]: cat 'test'
0 1 2
```

Here I'm actually writing to a file, and displaying that with system `cat`, but I could also write to string buffer.

But I can do better.  `savetxt` just writes the array, one row at a time, to the file.  I could use the same formatting style directly.

I create a `fmt` string, with a `%` specification for each item in `a` (here a 1d array).  Then `fmt%tuple(...)` formats it.  That's just straight forward Python string formatting.

```
In [144]: fmt = ', '.join(['%d']*a.shape[0])
In [145]: fmt
Out[145]: '%d, %d, %d'
In [146]: fmt%tuple(a.tolist())
Out[146]: '0, 1, 2'
```

I could add a `-` and indention, colon, etc to that formatting.

================================

```
import numpy as np

class A:
    def __init__(self, anArray):
        self.a_array = anArray

    def __repr__(self):
        astr = ['object: %s'%self.__class__]
        astr.append('a_array:')
        astr.append(self.repr_array())
        return '\n'.join(astr)

    def repr_array(self):
        a = self.a_array
        if a.ndim==1:
            a = a[None,:]
        fmt = ', '.join(['%d']*a.shape[1])
        fmt = '- '+fmt
        astr = []
        for row in a:
             astr.append(fmt%tuple(row))
        astr = '\n'.join(astr)
        return astr

print A(np.arange(3))

print A(np.ones((3,2)))
```

produces

```
object: __main__.A
a_array:
- 0, 1, 2
```

for a 1d array, and

```
object: __main__.A
a_array:
- 1, 1
- 1, 1
- 1, 1
```

for a 2d array.

=======================================

```
import yaml
def numpy_representer_str(dumper, data):
    # first cut ndarray yaml representer
    astr = ', '.join(['%s']*data.shape[0])%tuple(data)
    return dumper.represent_scalar('!ndarray:', astr)

def numpy_representer_seq(dumper, data):
    return dumper.represent_sequence('!ndarray:', data.tolist())

yaml.add_representer(np.ndarray, numpy_representer_str)
print (yaml.dump({'a':np.arange(4)},default_flow_style=False))

yaml.add_representer(np.ndarray, numpy_representer_seq)
print (yaml.dump({'a':np.arange(4)},default_flow_style=False))

class A:
    def __init__(self, anArray):
        self.a_array = anArray

    def __repr__(self):
        astr = ['object: %s'%self.__class__]
        astr.append('a_array:')
        astr.append(self.repr_array())
        return '\n'.join(astr)

    def repr_array(self):
        return yaml.dump(self.a_array)
print (A(np.arange(3)))
print (A(np.arange(6).reshape(2,3)))
```

With the different styles of numpy representer I get print like:

```
a: !ndarray: '0, 1, 2, 3'   # the string version

a: !ndarray:         # the sequence version
- 0
- 1
- 2
- 3

object: <class '__main__.A'>     # sequence version with 1d
a_array:
!ndarray: [0, 1, 2]

object: <class '__main__.A'>    # sequence version with 2d
a_array:
!ndarray:
- [0, 1, 2]
- [3, 4, 5]
```

Comment: My object has a complex structure (nested classes, dictionaries, basic data types, etc.) `yaml` seems a better solution than `pprint` or user-defined recursive structure print out. However, `yaml` prints out `array` one value at a time (as required for loading), whereas for display-only I need my print out to look compact (it will *not* be loaded later).

Comment: You could still use my array formatting ideas with `yaml`.  http://pyyaml.org/wiki/PyYAMLDocumentation#Constructorsrepresentersresolvers

Comment: I added a first cut (two actually) at an array representer.  I demo it both as standalong yaml dump and as part of your object formatting.

Comment: Great solution. When I run it, a FutureWarning comes up from representer. Is this avoidable? `C:\...\yaml\representer.py:135: FutureWarning: comparison to 'None' will result in an elementwise object comparison in the future.
  if data in [None, ()]:`

Comment: From your comment I can only guess at the location and cause of the warning, and I can't reproduce it  My guess is some data value is `None` (but not necessarily the newly added array).

Comment: Thanks. The error message was raised from running your code. It doesn't seem to have any explicit None values. Not sure yet what's going on, but I like the solution and accept it :) If you ever discover the source of the error, please let me know.

Comment: There's a line in `SafeRepresenter` that reads `if data in [None, ()]:`, which could end up trying `data==None`, while `data is None` is a better test.  I'm not sure why my tests don't raise the warning.  May be some sort of version issue.

Answer (score 1):

You can marshal your numpy array to a list when representing in your A object. Then unmarshal it when retrieving from your object:

```
class A:
    def __init__(self):
        from numpy import array
        self.a_lst = [1,2,3]

    def __repr__(self):
        from yaml import dump
        return dump(self, default_flow_style=False)

    # convert internal list to numpy array before returning.
    @property
    def my_arr(self):
        return array(self.a_lst)

    # convert array to list before storing internally.
    @my_arr.setter
    def my_arr(self, array):
        self.a_lst = array.tolist()

print(repr(A()))
```

The key is to ensure that you are storing the array as a plain python list while inside your object so you can ensure you can do a yaml dump.

A possibly better alternative is to use the built-in `dump` functionality provided by numpy. See [answer here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5951368/276949).

Comment: Thanks Martin. Actually, I need to store it as `array`, but output it as if it was a list. I thought there may be a `yaml.representer` (or simpler) solution for it. All internal computations would be done on `array`, which itself is a product of internal computations. So, storing `array` would be natural. However, `yaml` does not print it nicely (once error is handled) :(

Comment: Assuming your object is storing only `a_array` as a member, you could do the following: `a = A(); dump(a.a_array.tolist(), default_flow_style=False)`.

Comment: That'd be too trivial. In actuality, there are other class-scope structures, including nested class compositions (which also need to be printed). For now, I just wanted to focus on nice-printing `array` :)